# Bitbcuket server integration with AWS API gateway / Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket, aws-api-gateway

Problem:
Goal - Integrate Bitbucket server which is running in a container/EC2 from AWS-1 account with [ APIGateway-->Lambda-->S3-->Codepipeline ] in AWS-2 account for autodeploying of code whenever there is push in to the bitbucket.
I had setup the infra on AWS-2 account by running cloudforamtion. And while testing / invoking the API gateway from Bitbucket in webhook, it is giving the 'forbidden' error

```
[
Response details
HTTP status:403
Headers

x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Server: Server
Connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException
Content-Length: 23
Date: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Via: 1.1 localhost (Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (cache))
Content-Type: application/json

Body

**{"message":"Forbidden"}**
]
```

I have installed bitbucket server on my laptop to test.
However, when I invoke api gateurl from the postman or bitbucket server on my laptop I am getting **expected** exception from lambda/api gateway

```
[

Response details
HTTP status:502
Headers
x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amzn-ErrorType: InternalServerErrorException
Content-Length: 36
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2020 16:25:21 GMT
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Via: 1.1 localhost (Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (cache))
Content-Type: application/json
Body
{"message": "Internal server error"}

]
```

The owner of AWSaccount-1 mentioning that resource policy for bit bucket allows all inbound and outbound calls. However he did run curl command from bitbucket hosting container/ec2, got same forbidden error.

I am so confused here, can you please help me or let me know I need to provide more information.
note - this is my first question in stackoverflow :)